# Get the parameter string in javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these links :

Block 1 :

```
<a href="/Products?dep=56&cat=252&tab=2">Adapters</a>
<a href="/Products?dep=58&cat=654&tab=2">Battery</a>
```

After click on the link in Block1 , then I start to click on Block2:

Block 2 :

```
<a href="javascript:SearchClick();"><img src ="/Content/Images/Top/searchbutton.png"/></a>
```

I can get the parameter value such as dep=56,cat=654 by using these jquery.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
   var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
   var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
   var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null){
         return "";
    }else{
         return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

   function SearchClick() {

        var cur_url = window.location.href;
        var depId       = getParameterByName("dep");
        var catId       = getParameterByName("cat");
        var searchStr   = getParameterByName("search");
        var url_add = "";

        if (depId != "") {
            url_add += "&dep=" + depId;
        }

        window.location = "/Products?tab=2"+ url_add;

    }
```

But now I exchanged the link in Block 1 with

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' dep='" + work.ID + "'>" + work.ProName + "</a> 
//it works well
```

So how can I get the value of `dep` in Block 1 by using javascript or jquery when I click on the the Block 2 link?

Thanks so much for all your answers.

Comment: @socheta you cannot add custom defined attributes in html elements.

Comment: Add custom attributes in html elements works but you can't get them on another page.

Comment: I don't see a single piece of jQuery in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you put an ID on the A tag, like so:

```
<a id="myLink" href='javascript:void(0);' dep='" + work.ID + "'>" + work.ProName + "</a>
```

then you could use the following JQuery to get the value of work ID:

```
$("#myLink").attr("dep")
```

or plain old Javascript like so (assuming you've still got that ID on the A tag):

```
document.getElementById("myLink").getAttribute("dep")
```

**EDIT: I've put it in the click for you, here is all my code:**

```
<a id="block1Link" href='javascript:void(0);' dep="56">Adapters</a> 
<br />
<br />
<a href="javascript:SearchClick();">Click</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SearchClick() {
        var department = $("#block1Link").attr("dep");
        alert(department);
}
</script>
```

Or if you want to use Javascript swap the var department line with this line:

```
var department = document.getElementById("block1Link").getAttribute("dep");
```

Comment: Hey sorry what did you actually change in your edit? It looks the same :S

Comment: I've edited mine again to now put it on the Search Click for you.